# Monolog cannot write logs after upgrading to PHP 7.0

Tags: ubuntu, php

Every request to the server results in this as it's response:

```
Error in exception handler:
    The stream or file "/home/forge/default/app/storage/logs/fpm-fcgi-2016-09-09.log" could not be opened:
        failed to open stream:
            Permission denied in /home/forge/default/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
```

I've checked, and the dir permissions are 0755.

Server system is Ubuntu 14.04. Nothing in the Nginx logs suggesting there is a problem there.

What might be going on?

Comment: You need to ensure that the user used to run your daemon server has write permission set for the log file, and potentially over subfolders where it is stored.
Also check the owner of the log file.
`0755` is not enough info to determine if this correct in your context.

Comment: When I check, I get this `drwxr-xr-x 11 forge forge 4096 Jul  9  2015 storage`. I just deleted all the log files to allow it to write fresh ones, but same error.

Comment: What about the `app` and `logs` dir ?

Comment: @krisFR `drwxrwxr-x 13 forge forge   4096 Apr  2 08:08 app` and `drwxr-xr-x 2 forge forge  4096 Sep  9 19:31 logs`

Comment: let's continue to check the same for the `default` folder, then `ps -ef | grep forge`